# Click function is not working on $(document)

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

```
alert("hi");
$(document).on('click', '.customerstory-section-header', function() {
   $('.overlay-Div').hide();
   $(this).parent().children().children("div.overlay-Div").toggle();
   $("#Jananayak-Stories-Section").hide();
   $("#Customer-Stories-Section").show();
});
```

The `click` function is working on a `div`. The classname selector is the same in markup and here in jQuery code. If I put an `alert` outside the click function, it's working, the alert is coming. If I put alert inside the click function, it's not working. `console` is not working there. Can anybody help me, please?

```
$(".customerstory-section-header").hover(function(){
  alert("hi");
   $('.overlay-Div').hide();
   $(this).parent().children().children("div.overlay-Div").toggle();
   $("#Jananayak-Stories-Section").hide();
   $("#Customer-Stories-Section").show();
});
```

I changed the event hover and just tried. Its not working. if i put alert outside the function, alert is coming. So JS file is loading. But none of the event handler is not working. Please help me here

Comment: Is your jQuery added correctly and working?

Comment: Please add your `html` and improve your question

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error... share your html also

Comment: We *need* to see your HTML to be able to help you. There is no reason that what you've shown wouldn't work, assuming your HTML is in the correct state.

Comment: Probably click event propagation between `.customerstory-section-header` and `document` is stopped in some way

Comment: So if hover (directly bound to element) doesn't work, you can have selector issue or maybe just CSS rule making it unresponsive `pointer-events: none;`. Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue, it could be many many things that cause this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "body" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Body Clicked" );
  });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/e640ggmy/

Comment: If its not working in your case there will be some other issue happening with your DOM. Please check your browser's console by pressing `F12` and checkout the errors you are getting.

Comment: Well, as he didn't posted the complete code so I/you can't figure it out whats happening exactly out of the box. Secondly, the answer I've posted is simple and working.

Comment: But the OP's one is better imho. Better because he doesn't have to bound extra event (document pseudo ready one) as `document` is available at any time, unlike `body`

Comment: This is perfect solution. Its working absolutely fine... @hmd Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2349508 BUT this is fired if you click anywhere on the `body`... This has nothing to do with your expected behaviour, regarding your posted code

Comment: I have removed body element and i had put my class selector.. Its worked.. !!

Comment: Glad that it helped you @user2349508 :)

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery are you using ?
The .on() function is supported since 1.7.1, if you are using an earlier version, you should instead use .bind(), .live() or .delegate()

[here is the difference between all of them](http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/)

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Also you can use the browser console and type $(document) to get the jquery object and expand it to see the functions it supports.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.customerstory-section-header', function(event) {
   ....
});
```

Comment: document.body helps for dynamic html too.

Comment: @DharaParmar `$(document).on('click', '.customerstory-section-header', function() {` will serve the same purpose.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a suggestion. Explain why OP need to use this code and what is/was wrong with his code.